# variadic boost bind type resolution

Tags: c++, templates, bind, boost-asio, variadic-templates

I'm trying to write an async logger which accepts variadic arguments that are then strung together using a variadic stringer and then pushed onto a single producer single consumer queue.

I'm stuck in my enqueue function part of my Log struct which looks as follows:

```
template <typename T>
std::string Log::stringer(T const & t){
    return boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(t);
}

template<typename T, typename ... Args>
std::string Log::stringer(T const & t, Args const & ... args){
    return stringer(t) + stringer(args...);
}

 template<typename T, typename ... Args>
 void Log::enqueue(T & t, Args & ... args){
     boost::function<std::string()> f 
        = boost::bind(&Log::stringer<T &, Args & ...>,this,
                      boost::ref(t),
                      boost::forward<Args>(args)...);
 /// the above statement fails to compile though if i use 'auto f' it works ->
 /// but then it is unclear to me what the signature of f really is ?                              

 // at this point i would like to post the functor f onto my asio::io_service, 
 // but not able to cause it's not clear to me what the type of f is.
 // I think it should be of type boost::function<std::string()>

 }
```

Inside main(), I call

```
  Log t_log;
  t_log.enqueue("hello"," world");
```

Comment: If you could post more complete code, eg on ideone, I can try to help you. I don't usually do boost, but this looks interesting

Comment: @InnocentBystander Code is posted @ https://ideone.com/WdAkD7. boost can be substitued with std:: for all practical purposes.

Comment: .. or just use Coliru, which provides Boost.

Comment: @Columbo , Also posted at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b3f15c3eb47ee3f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion for the function you ask about:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args> void enqueue(T &t, Args const&... args) {
    this->io_service->post([=]{ 
                auto s = stringer(t, args...);
                //std::fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s.c_str()); 
            });
}
```

This works with GCC and Clang (GCC 4.9 or later because of a known issue with captured variadic packs).

But really, I'd reconsider the design at hand, and certainly start *a lot* simpler until you know what areas deserve further optimization.

### Questionables

There are many things I don't understand about this code:

- Why are the arguments being taken by non-const reference
- Why are you subsequently using `std::forward<>` on them (you already now the value category, and it's not going to change)
- Why are you passing the stringization to an `io_service`?

  - the queue is going to introduce locking (kind of refuting the lockfree queue) and
  - the stringization is going to have its result ignored...
- Why would you use `boost::function` here? This incurs a (another) dynamic allocation and an indirect dispatch... Just post `f`
- Why are the arguments bound by reference in the first place? If you're going to process the arguments on a different thread, this leads to Undefined Behaviour. E.g. imagine the caller doing

  ```
  char const msg[] = "my message"; // perhaps some sprintf output
  l.enqueue(cat.c_str(), msg);
  ```

  The `c_str()` is stale after the `enqueue` returned and `msg` goes out of scope soon, or gets overwritten with other data.
- Why are you using `bind` approaches when you clearly have `c++11` support (because you used `std::forward<>` and attributes)?
- Why are you using a lockfree queue (do anticipate to be constantly logging at max CPU? In that case, logging is the core functionality of you application and you should probably think this through a bit (a lot) more rigorously (e.g. write into preallocated alternating buffers and decide on max backlog etc).

  In all other cases, you probably want at most 1 single thread running on a lockfree queue. This would likely already be overkill (spinning a thread constantly is expensive). Instead, you could gracefully fallback to yields/synchronization if there's nothing to do n cycles.
- You can just bind to a `shared_ptr`. This is a **lot** safer and more convenient than binding to `.get()`

  > In my sample below I've just removed the need for `scoped_ptr`s by not allocating everything from the heap (why was that?). (You can use `boost::optional<work>` if you needed work.)
- The explicit memory-order load/stores give me bad vibes too. The way they're written would make sense only if exactly two threads are involved in the flag, but this is in no way apparent to me at the moment (threads are created all around).

  On most platforms there will be no difference, and in light of the above, the presence of explicit memory ordering stands out as a clear code smell
- The same thing applies to the attempts to forcibly inline certain functions. You can trust your compiler and you should probably refrain from second guessing it until you know you have a bottleneck caused by suboptimal generated code
- Since you intend to give threads thread affinity, **do** use thread locals. Either use GCC/MSVC extensions in C++03 (__thread) or use c++11 `thread_local`, e.g. in `pop()`

  ```
  thread_local std::string s;
  s.reserve(1000);
  s.resize(0);
  ```

  <strike>This enormously reduces the number of allocations (at the cost of making pop() non-reentrant, which is not required.</strike>

  > I later noticed this `pop()` is limited to a single thread
- What is the use of having that lockfree queue if all you do is ... spinlock manually around it?

  ```
  void push(std::string const &s) {
      while (std::atomic_flag_test_and_set_explicit(&this->lock, std::memory_order_acquire))
          ;
      while (!this->q->push(s))
          ;
      std::atomic_flag_clear_explicit(&this->lock, std::memory_order_release);
  }
  ```

---

### Cleanup Suggestion

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10ecc5d92b913bed)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>
#include <boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

/*
 * safe for use from a single thread only
 */
template <unsigned line_maxchars = 1000>
class Log {
  public:
    Log(std::string const &logFileName, int32_t queueSize)
      : fp(stderr), // std::fopen(logFileName.c_str(),"w")
        _shutdown(false),
        _thread(&Log::pop, this),
        _queue(queueSize)
    { }

    void pop() {
        std::string s;
        s.reserve(line_maxchars);

        struct timeval ts;
        while (!_shutdown) {
            while (_queue.pop(s)) {
                gettimeofday(&ts, NULL);
                std::fprintf(fp, "%li.%06li %s\n", ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_usec, s.c_str());
            }
            std::fflush(fp); // RECONSIDER HERE?
        }

        while (_queue.pop(s)) {
            gettimeofday(&ts, NULL);
            std::fprintf(fp, "%li.%06li %s\n", ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_usec, s.c_str());
        }
    }

    template <typename S, typename T> void stringer(S& stream, T const &t) {
        stream << t;
    }

    template <typename S, typename T, typename... Args>
    void stringer(S& stream, T const &t, Args const &... args) {
        stringer(stream, t);
        stringer(stream, args...);
    }

    template <typename T, typename... Args> void enqueue(T &t, Args const&... args) {
        thread_local char buffer[line_maxchars] = {};
        boost::iostreams::array_sink as(buffer);
        boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::array_sink> stream(as);

        stringer(stream, t, args...);

        auto output = as.output_sequence();
        push(std::string(output.first, output.second));
    }

    void push(std::string const &s) {
        while (!_queue.push(s));
    }

    ~Log() {
        _shutdown = true;
        _thread.join();

        assert(_queue.empty());
        std::fflush(fp);
        std::fclose(fp);

        fp = NULL;
    }

  private:
    FILE *fp;
    boost::atomic_bool _shutdown;

    boost::thread _thread;
    boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<std::string> _queue;
};

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

    {
        Log<> l("/tmp/junk.log", 1024);

        for (int64_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            l.enqueue("hello ", i, " world");
        }
    }

    std::cout << duration_cast<microseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count() << "μs\n";
}
```

As you can see, I've reduced the code by a third. I've documented the fact that it's only safe for use from a single thread.

Asio is gone. Lexical cast is gone. Things have meaningful names. No more memory order fiddling. No more thread affinity fiddling. No more *inline envy*. No more tedious string allocations.

The things that you'd likely benefit the most from is

- make the array_sinks/buffers pooled and stored in the queue by reference
- not flush on every log

Comment: I retracted my answer. I made it compile by brute force, not being able to understand the design. `+1` to you sir

Comment: @InnocentBystander Just to be constructive as well, I've added my idea of what constitutes a much simpler start: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10ecc5d92b913bed) - _(I'm pretty certain is more efficient to boot, OP)_

Comment: @sehe thank your for your detailed reply and critique on the design i was pursuing. A lot of the code is experimental. For instance I created the thread pool to push onto the queue cause I was observing jitter (spikes of upto 35 microsecs) and my suspicion was the original single pusher thread was still blocked working. I'm not sure what's wrong with the atomic flag load/store combination in place? Could you explain this. Isn't the acquire/release fence synchronized across all threads ? This was my first shot at variadics, that's why the clumsiness around boost::function and stuff.

Comment: @sehe I'm also trying to make enqueue a non-blocking call, even if it be called from a single thread.

Comment: I've created a chat here for clarifying the comments: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69990/on-lockfree-logging-queuing-and-memory-order

Comment: I've done a performance comparison of several variations discussed in chat and came up with a simplified approach that allows the caller to leave the formatting to the logging thread (that is still correct). [performance stats](http://downloads.sehe.nl/stackoverflow/q28254996/smart-lambda.html), and [explanations](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69990/on-lockfree-logging-queuing-and-memory-order)